# Testing the web api that accepts JSON as input

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web api that needs to accept JSON as input that is sent by the called client side application. Below is the Code

```
 public class SetNameController : ApiController
 {
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromBody] CodeDTO.RootObject bCode)
 {
  string Bar_Code = bCode.Barcode.ToString();

  if (Bar_Code == "" || Bar_Code == null)
  { 
   ....
   return OK(response)
 }
```

Here I am not sure How the client application call this Web API, the URL can be just like http://localhost:41594/api/SetName can it accept the JSON? Also can I test this using PostMan or Fiddler?

Comment: Should be '/api/SetName/Get'. Pass the bCode parameter formatted as JSON in the request body. As a side note naming the action 'Get' but decorating it with '[HttpPost]' is confusing.

Comment: Show the screen of the postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the following:

- Method: POST
- Header: Content Type

[image]

Then, provide the payload json data in Body as raw:

[image]

Also, change the name of the action `Get` which might cause confusion. If you still cannot hit your api, you can use route urls by decorating the action with `[Route('yourURL')]` attribute and change that accordingly in postman.